# Scala Akka gPRC: server don't answer

Tags: scala, grpc, akka-grpc

I have 2 microservices with common proto-file:

```
 service GeoService {
    rpc GetGeoPoint (GeoRequest) returns (GeoPoint) {};
    rpc CreateGeoPoint (GeoPoint) returns (GeoPoint) {};
 }

message GeoRequest {
     int32 id = 5;
     string dateTime = 6;
 }

message GeoPoint {
    int32 id = 1;
    int32 latitude = 2;
    int32 longitude = 3;
    string dateTime = 4;
 }
```

1 microservice: Running on port 8081. Realise gRPC-client on Akka.grpc. I don't override automatically generated GeoService methods, as their only aim is to pass the request (GeoRequest or GeoPoint) to another microservice.

Connection with server is carried out by:

```
 val clientSettings = GrpcClientSettings.connectToServiceAt("127.0.0.1", 8080).withTls(false)
 val client: GeoServiceClient = GeoServiceClient(clientSettings)
```

And method call:

```
 val savedGeoPoint = client.createGeoPoint(geoPoint)
```

2 microservice: Running on port 8080. Realise gRPC-client on scalapb-runtime-grpc (not Akka grpc). Server methods overrided for saving some data in store and retrieving saved data from store:

```
 override def createGeoPoint(geoPoint: GeoPoint): Future[GeoPoint] =
  GeoRepository.save(geoPoint)
```

In fact client in 1 mictoservice successfully invoke createGeoPoint-method in server (2 microservice). Incoming data saved to store. But result don't return to the client.   Method "val savedGeoPoint = client.createGeoPoint(geoPoint)" in Client-microservice don't return any result.

Am I missing something usefull?

Comment: Can you clarify what the actual error is? And out of interest, why use two different gRPC libraries in the two services?

Comment: This is strangeб иге It does not show any errors. I use different gRPC libraries  for experimental goals

Comment: So what do you mean by "don't return any result"? Does the function lock up and never return? Does it return a `Future` that never completes? Does it complete with an error or an empty value of some sort?

Comment: Sorry for delay with answer. Override method createGeoPoint(geoPoint: GeoPoint)returns Future<Not complete>.

Comment: So it returns a `Future` but the `Future` never completes? Seem odd as the library should have a timeout.  Try with a different client (python is pretty easy) and see if you have the same problem then you can tell whether it is the client or the server that is not completing.

Comment: I tried to send with BloomRPC. And no such problem was found. Possibly, the problem on client side